# multiple instances of UI in winform

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, components

I have a winform application that contains, by default, a ui with about a dozen standard components. Each set of components represents a hardware device which the application communicates with. I need to be able replicate, or duplicate multiple instances of this set of controls so that the main form contains 1, 10, or 100 instances of this UI, using a tab interface to hold each set of 10 "control interfaces". I'm looking for suggestions on how to best handle and manage this. In other words, how to best create and manage multiple instances of what might normally be a single user interface. I'm thinking I can easily create a list of objects, each one being a container of all the components that make up a single representation of the hardware being communicated with.

While I've created the interface using the designer, I'm thinking it may not be practical to use the designer for the creation of all the additional "component sets", which will be determined at installation time. I guess essentially I need a list or array of the "this.components" object container for each instance of the interface. Any suggestions on how to approach and tackle such a problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: It depends how you want to organize them. What they are? Windows? Docked controls? Dockable windows?

Comment: It is certainly best to avoid considering creating a user interface with 1200+ controls.  That's going to suck mud badly.  It otherwise sounds like you need a UserControl.

Comment: @HansPassant "to suck mud badly" LOL sometimes I'm sorry I'm not an english speaker!!! LOL

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with DockPanelSuite

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/

I may post some sample code to get you started but it's fairly staright forward!